# MATLAB: Plotting with timestamp in UTC time for recorded data

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, matlab-guide

I have this data recorded (CO and Temperature...etc) with the timestamp in UTC time. I would like to visualize it on MATLAB with time on the X-axis instead of sample number. Here is [Snapshot from my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhdMi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to convert your UTC time to a MATLAB `datenum`, then plot it and use `datetick('x')` to force the x-axis to show the actual time.

If you load the time data as a vector of strings into a variable called (for instance) `UTC`, you can do this as follows:

```
time = datenum(UTC,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
plot(time,your_data_here);
datetick('x');
```